# How to drag an item out from an Iframe and drop onto the parent

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a folder tree view on the left page which was in a <div> tag. The left page was the iframe container which contained the file list.

When I want to drag the files out from the iframe, I got a headache. No matter if the containment option was set to 'parent' or 'window', I just can't drag out elements in the iframe container.

How can I do this?

Comment: other browsers seem to forbid it, but firefox seems to allow it. I have an iframe on a different domain and I can drag out images from it into an mce box on the parent page

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to drag an element out from an iframe to a parent document here I made jQuery plugin for it:

https://github.com/Vatia13/dragoutfromiframe

Comment: Wow I just found this, and this is really cool. Can you make a demo of this working?

Answer (score -1):

Interacting between iframes and the parent frame can be challenging (if not impossible if the iframe holds content from another website/domain). Dependent on the situation, using a DIV, populated with content (either directly through PHP, or by using the jQuery `$.load()` function) may be a better option.

Then the dragged object and its target are within the same page - much simpler.

Comment: "DIV" was hidden in the original version of the question. Does this change the answer?